# How can I config the jpa-config.xml to allow the entityManageFactory auto scanning two packages at the same time?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jpa, spring-security

I'm trying to integrate an library to an other one, the following code is the content in jpa-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example1" />
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
                <entry key="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
                <entry key="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="INFO" />
                <entry key="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I'm just wondering if I can do something like this:

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>com.example1</value>
        <value>com.example2</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

Comment: Have you tried it and read the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan-java.lang.String...-)?!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple packages to scan with below (as included in your question):

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
   <list>
     <value>com.example1</value>
     <value>com.example2</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

The `packagesToScan` attribute is there for xml less configuration ie. no persistence.xml... When using a persistence xml it follows the JPA spec.